# Passing a string with an argument using argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have been reading about the `argparse` module in Python and also did a bit of research but could not find a clean technique to pass a string through an argument.

Basically I would like to have this working:

```
myProg -a=FOO
```

and then be able to sample the string `"FOO"`.

I kind of got it working, but `myProg -a+FOO`  would pass `"+FOO"` into the arguments namespace. I can probably do a secondary check, but just wondering if there is a proper way to do this, to limit the argument format to `-a=` and catch anything else as an error.

Comment: `argparse` assumes Unix-style command lines, and `-a=FOO` is an unusual format for that (it would ordinarily be `-aFOO` or `--aaa FOO`). A secondary check is probably your best option.

Comment: @Sneftel I think you meant `-a FOO` and `--a=FOO`.

Comment: Both are acceptable, but that's a good point.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to replace FOO with a directory path. Is that going to help? Maybe a "dir" type of a limitation?

Comment: `--a='/home/me/dir/afile'` should work. Check `sys.argv` to see how the shell splits your argument line.